# mrgsolve R error: the model dll file doesn't exist

Tags: r

I am running the following code and ran into an error.

```
library(mrgsolve)
library(dplyr)
#create two compartment PK modeling for Lebrikizumab and APG777
mod_leb <- mread("pk2", modlib())
mod_apg <- mread("pk2", modlib())

#Update the models with respective CL levels for Lebrikizumab and APG777
#Human CL levels are translated from cynomolgus monkey data from the poster
mod_leb <- param(mod_leb, CL=0.945)
mod_apg <- param(mod_apg, CL=1.872)
mod_leb %>%
  ev(amt=250) %>%
  Req(CP) %>%
  mrgsim(delta=0.1, end=2160) %>%
  plot()
```

Error : [loadso] the model dll file doesn't exist

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot':
There was a problem accessing the model shared object.
Either the model object was corrupted or the model was
not properly compiled and/or loaded. If the model is
not loaded, use `loadso(mod)` to do so. This is usually
required for parallel simulation on a worker node that
was not forked (e.g. when using future::multisession).
Also check mrgsolve:::funset(mod) for more information.

Anyone knows what's going on?